# Error: TempsController could not be found.Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp

I want files to be uploaded to files folder and their names to be submitted from temp.ctp to tbl_temps table of Temp database. I have created the Model by the name of Temp in models folder. But I am receiving following

Error: TempsController could not be found.Cake PHP.

Error: Create the class TempsController below in file: app\Controller\TempsController.php

temp.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->Create("Temp",array("action"=>"temp","enctype"=>"multipart/form-data"));
echo $this->Form->input("file.",array("label"=>false,"div"=>false,"type"=>"file"));
echo $this->Form->input("file.",array("label"=>false,"div"=>false,"type"=>"file"));
?>
<input type="submit"/>
<?php   
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

PagesController

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');


public $uses = array("Temp");


public function temp(){

    if($this->request->is("post")){
        $uploaded_files="";
        foreach($this->data["Temp"]["file"] as $file1){
            $ret_value = $this->PImage->upload($file1,'/app/webroot/files');
            if (isset($ret_value[1]) && !empty($ret_value[1])) {
                                $msgString .= "- File not valid.<br>";
                            } 
            else {
                if($uploaded_files){
                    $uploaded_files.= ",*".$ret_value[0];
                }
                else{
                    $uploaded_files=$ret_value[0];
                }
            }
        }
        $this->request->data["Temp"]["file"]=$uploaded_files;
        $this->Temp->save($this->data);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear in what you should do:
**Error: Create the class TempsController below in file: app\Controller\TempsController.php**

You should first understand the [Model-View-Controller principle](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html) and then move on to create the [Controller](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html) for your `Temp` model.

You will have to create a file `/app/Controller/TempsController.php`:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class TempsController extends AppController {

    /* this action will be accessible at '/temps/index' with default routing */

    public function index() {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```